# Some assignments in the definition of \parbox

Tags: boxes, latex-base

Why are these assignments necessary in the LaTeX's definition of `\parbox`?

```
\let\hss\vss\let\unhbox\unvbox
```

**EDIT**

I should have added that I wondered if the assignments will affect any in-parbox calls (i.e., calls made by the parbox material) to the original definitions of the macros `\hss` and `\unhbox`, since compatibility problems might arise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `\@iiiparbox`, you have:

```
\long\def\@iiiparbox#1#2[#3]#4#5{%
  \leavevmode
  \@pboxswfalse
  \setlength\@tempdima{#4}%
  \@begin@tempboxa\vbox{\hsize\@tempdima\@parboxrestore#5\@@par}%
    \ifx\relax#2\else
      \setlength\@tempdimb{#2}%
      \edef\@parboxto{to\the\@tempdimb}%
    \fi
    \if#1b\vbox
    \else\if #1t\vtop
    \else\ifmmode\vcenter
    \else\@pboxswtrue $\vcenter
    \fi\fi\fi
    \@parboxto{\let\hss\vss\let\unhbox\unvbox
       \csname bm@#3\endcsname}%
    \if@pboxsw \m@th$\fi
  \@end@tempboxa}
```

Argument `#3` is actually position argument, so `\csname bm@#3\endcsname` would make `\bm@c`, `\bm@l`, `\bm@r`, `\bm@b`,  `\bm@t`, and `\bm@s`. But these are defined as:

```
\def\bm@c{\hss\unhbox\@tempboxa\hss}
\def\bm@l{\unhbox\@tempboxa\hss}\let\bm@t\bm@l
\def\bm@r{\hss\unhbox\@tempboxa}\let\bm@b\bm@r
\def\bm@s{\unhbox\@tempboxa}
```

Obviously these are for horizontal mode so in `\parbox`, or `minipage` environment, you need to have vertical version of these so that explains the existence of `\let\hss\vss\let\unhbox\unvbox` in the definition of `\@iiiparbox`.

Comment: Very good explanation. I believe that the *real* reason was to save some memory, avoiding permanent distinct definitions for the (more frequent) horizontal case and the vertical case. When LaTeX2e was released, saving as much memory as possible was very important.